# Can not download Youtube video as a single file using Flashgot

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, youtube

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Most of the times, when I try to download a Youtube video using [flashgot](https://flashgot.net/) extension for Firefox (version 14.0.2), I am not able to download the video as one file but multiple files.

Could you explain me why this happens and if there is something to do to get all my videos downloaded as a one file?

Here is a screenshot of the problem I described:

[image]

Comment: To me that just looks like a list of different formats the video is available in. Does the plugin allow you just to select one of them and confirm that?

Comment: The screenshot you linked doesn't show any `mp3` [original comment was edited to `mp4`] files, but some addons/plugins allow you just to download the audio. Are the files all the same size or varying sizes? (Nvm the first part then)

Comment: It seems then, that some videos (or most of them) are actually split into several parts on youtube's end and not a fault of the plugin itself. I can't confirm this tho, since there is no information on youtube's end. I'll install flashgot on my browser and see if I can make sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and tested Flashgot on Firefox using Windows 7. The files are indeed the same files, just encoded differently. You mentioned that there are differences in length, which is something I cannot explain. I never encountered that issue.

I used the same youtube video you showed in your screenshot example.

[image]

[image]